# Is there a way to push Azure DevOpsRelease pipeline logs into Log Analytics?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-monitoring

We would need to store the deployment logs for all customers for a period of one year and was wondering if there is a way of pushing the Azure Devops release logs into Log Analytics or Azure monitor?

Comment: Have you checked the api? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is not a direct way to push Azure Devops release logs into Log Analytics. But since there is Api to [get release logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and for [Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/), you can consider using the api to implement your requirement.