# Direct Azure DevOps pipeline logs to Log Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to direct the azure pipeline logs to log analytics. Currently, I am running a simple python script that sends basic custom logs to log analytics that runs at the end of the pipeline based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api) article, but I'm missing more detailed information like error messages in case the pipeline fails for example.

Are the logs stored somewhere I can retrieve them? like `/path/to/logs/buildId_yyyymmdd.log`

Answer (score 0):

> Are the logs stored somewhere I can retrieve them? like
> /path/to/logs/buildId_yyyymmdd.log

- You can view logs by navigating to the pipeline run summary and selecting the job and task. If a certain task is failing, check the logs for that task.
- In addition to viewing logs in the pipeline build summary, you can download complete logs which include additional diagnostic information.

Apart from pipeline diagnostic logs, the following specialized log types are available, and may contain information to help you troubleshoot.

1. Worker diagnostic logs
2. Agent diagnostic logs
3. Other logs

You can refer this documentation to know more information about the [specialized log types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops#worker-diagnostic-logs) in azure devops pipelines.

You can also refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164686/15968720) thread for more information about how to send azure devops release pipeline logs to log analytics & also about sending  [azure devops aduit logs](https://automate.guru/azure-devops-audit-logs-forwarding/) to log analytics.